# copy content of file in reverse order

Tags: c

I need to write a program that is copying the content of a file to another file and reverses it.
I found an example and read it through to understand what is going on.
The problem is that my program has to use two functions:

```
void reverse(char line[]){
   int i;
   int length;
   char tmp;
     ..
     ..
     ..
   return;
}
```

(no further paramters or local variables)

The second function does the rest of the work(opens files, copies files, closes files)
The main program only reads the name of the files and calls the copy function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char line[])
{
    int  i;
    int  length;
    char temp;
    if (line == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(line);
    for (i = 0 ; i < length / 2 + length % 2 ; ++i)
    {
        if (line[i] == line[length - i - 1])
            continue;
        temp                 = line[i];
        line[i]              = line[length - i - 1];
        line[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return;
}




 int main() 
{ 

    FILE *src_fh, *dst_fh; 
    char src_fn[256+1], dst_fn[256+1]; 


    printf("Enter Source File Name:\n"); 
    fgets(src_fn, sizeof(src_fn), stdin); reverse(src_fn); 


    if( (src_fh = fopen(src_fn, "r")) == NULL ) 
    { 
        printf("ERROR: Source File %s Failed To Open...\n",src_fn); 
        return(-1); 
    } 


    printf("Enter Destination File Name:\n"); 
    fgets(dst_fn, sizeof(dst_fn), stdin); reverse(dst_fn); 


    if( (dst_fh = fopen(dst_fn, "w+")) == NULL ) 
    { 
        fclose(src_fh); 
        printf("ERROR: Destination File %s Failed To Open...\n",dst_fn); 
        return(-2); 
    } 

    int ch; 
    while( (ch = fgetc(src_fh)) != EOF ) 
    { 
        fputc(ch, dst_fh); 
    } 


    fclose(src_fh); 
    fclose(dst_fh); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Judging from your function definition, I'm guessing you're only supposed to reverse the contents of each line, right? So if the file has lines "abc" and "def", you're supposed to output lines "cba" and "fed" (lines in the original order but with the letters within each line reversed)? 'Cause that's very different from reversing the content of the entire file (which would be newline "fed" newline "cba").

Comment: What is the problem with the function `void reverse(char line[])` *no further paramters or local variables*? That function you posted **does** have local variables and the function is equivalent to `void reverse(char *line)` which also passes all the information required if `line` is a 0-terminated string.

Comment: @JoeWhite Yes, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don`t know how to start. In the exercise it says don`t define more local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to swap the first character with the last, the second with the pre-last, and so on.

You actually don't need the `int temp` variable, but since it seems to be required, here it is

```
void reverse(char line[])
{
    int  i;
    int  length;
    char temp;
    if (line == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(line);
    for (i = 0 ; i < length / 2 + length % 2 ; ++i)
    {
        if (line[i] == line[length - i - 1])
            continue;
        temp                 = line[i];
        line[i]              = line[length - i - 1];
        line[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

This is an improved version, without `int temp`, instead we store the result of `length /  2 + length % 2` so it's not recalculated on each iteration

```
void reverse(char line[])
{
    int i;
    int length;
    int half;

    if (line == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(line);
    half   = length / 2 + length % 2;
    for (i = 0 ; i < half ; ++i)
    {
        if (line[i] == line[length - i - 1])
            continue;
        line[length]         = line[i];
        line[i]              = line[length - i - 1];
        line[length - i - 1] = line[length];
    }
    line[length] = '\0';
    return;
}
```

just use the location of the terminating `'\0'` byte as the `temp` when swapping.

For the second function, read each line using `fgets` and write it to the file with `fprintf`, just remember to remove the newline character from the read strings, you can use the `chomp` function y posted for that, if you don't remove the newline, the reversed lines will have the newline at the beginning of the line.

Comment: What to do if `line` contains a literal `\0`?

Comment: Since the function signature is given, i think they will be null terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

The prameter name `line` in the prototype `void reverse(char line[])` seems to give a hint, how the given exercise might be intended to be solved.

1. split the file in lines
2. reverse every line
3. reverse the order of the lines

Nevertheless you should watch out following this strategy, as there is still a really nasty gotcha involved, if your file may contain *any* data.

In this case you'll get in big trouble finding the end of `line[]` as '\0' termination might get confused with a literal '\0' in the line.

As a workaround you might try to replace any literal occurance of '/0' by the sequence '\0' 'x' and mark the end of your line by the sequence '\0' '-' or whatever before passing it to `reverse()` and reaversing the substitution after writing the reversed line to the file.

Unfortunately this attempt doesn't look too elegant, but maybe reversing a file the way it is meant to be done in the exercise isn't really elegant anyays.

Answer (score 0):

```
the following code 
1) incorporates proper error checking
2) outputs each input line, reversed, to the output file.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* chomp(char* p)
{
    int len;
    if(!p) return(p);
    if( (len=strlen(p))<=0 ) return(p);
    if( p[len-1] == '\n' ) { p[--len] = '\0'; }
    if( p[len-1] == '\r' ) { p[--len] = '\0'; }
    return(p);
} // end function: chomp

int main()
{
    /* Create Usable Variables */
    FILE *src_fh = NULL;
    FILE *dst_fh = NULL;
    char src_fn[256+1] = {'\0'};
    char dst_fn[256+1] = {'\0'};
    char line[2048]    = {'\0'};

    /* Retrieve Source File Name From User */
    printf("Enter Source File Name:\n");
    if( NULL == (fgets(src_fn, sizeof(src_fn), stdin) ) )
    { // fgets failed
        perror("fgets for input file name failed" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    chomp(src_fn); // remove trailing newline characters

    /* Attempt Opening Source File For Reading */
    if( (src_fh = fopen(src_fn, "r")) == NULL )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        printf("ERROR: Source File %s Failed To Open...\n",src_fn);
        return(-1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen source file successful

    /* Retrieve Destination File Name From User */
    printf("Enter Destination File Name:\n");
    if( NULL == (fgets(dst_fn, sizeof(dst_fn), stdin) ) )
    { // then fgets failed
        perror( "fgets for output file name failed" );
        fclose(src_fh); // cleanup 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets for output file name successful

    chomp(dst_fn); // remove trailing newline characters

    /* Attempt Opening Destination File For Writing */
    if( NULL == (dst_fh = fopen(dst_fn, "w")) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for output file failed" );
        fclose(src_fh); // cleanup
        printf("ERROR: Destination File %s Failed To Open...\n",dst_fn);
        return(-2);
    }

    // implied else, fopen for output file successful

    int index;
    /* Copy Source File Contents (reversed, line by line) to destination file */
    while( NULL != (fgets(line, sizeof(line), src_fh) ) )
    {
        chomp(line); // remove trailing newline characters
        index = strlen(line) - 1; // -1 because arrays start with offset 0
                                  // and strlen returns offset to '\0'

        // output reversed line to file
        while( index >= 0 )
        {
            fputc( line[index], dst_fh );
            index--;
        } // end while

        fputc( '\n', dst_fh );
    } // end while

    /* Close Files On Success */
    fclose(src_fh);
    fclose(dst_fh);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```