# including function correctly in main program

Tags: c

Yesterday I already asked a question about the same program([copy content of file in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584155/copy-content-of-file-in-reverse-order)),
but now I don`t know how to call the second function correctly in the main program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char line[])
{
    int  i;
    int  length;
    char temp;
    if (line == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(line);
    for (i = 0 ; i < length / 2 + length % 2 ; ++i)
    {
        if (line[i] == line[length - i - 1])
            continue;
        temp                 = line[i];
        line[i]              = line[length - i - 1];
        line[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return;
}


char copying(char *src_file, char *dst_file) {

    fgets(src_file, sizeof(src_file), stdin); reverse(src_file); 

    if( (src_file = fopen(src_file, "r")) == NULL ) 
    { 
        printf("ERROR: Source File %s Failed To Open...\n",src_file); 
        return(-1); 
    } 

    fgets(dst_file, sizeof(dst_file), stdin);

    if( (dst_file = fopen(dst_file, "w+")) == NULL ) 
    { 
        fclose(src_file); 
        printf("ERROR: Destination File %s Failed To Open...\n",dst_file); 
        return(-2); 
    } 

    int ch; 
    while( (ch = fgetc(src_file)) != EOF ) 
    { 
        fputc(ch, dst_file); 
    } 

    fclose(src_file);  
    fclose(dst_file);

    return dst_file;
    }



int main() 
{ 
    char src_file[200], dst_file[200];

    printf("Enter Source File Name:\n"); 
    fgets(src_file, sizeof(src_file), stdin);

    printf("Enter Destination File Name:\n"); 
    fgets(dst_file, sizeof(dst_file), stdin);

    *dst_file = copying(src_file, dst_file); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `src_file` and `dst_file` aren't declared in `main`.Also,The parameters need to have their type before them. There seems to be several other problems too!

Comment: Your `copying` has some severe syntax issues (semicolon, no curly braces). The code shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very broken, it wouldn't even compile. Here are some fixes:

- `char copying(char *src_file, char *dst_file)` - You have to specify the datatype of the arguments.
- `char copying(char *src_file, char *dst_file) { ...}` - Dont forget the brackets around your function
- You first have to declare the variables `src_file` and `dst_file` in `main`
- And **don't** declare them in your `copying` function, since they already defined as your arguments
- You are returning a `char` pointer, while the function definition of `copying` says it is only returning a 'char'.

Now if `src_file` and `dst_file` in your `main` function are **allocated** `char` pointers, then you are calling the function correctly.

I didn't go through all your code, so there might be more errors. Try to run the compiler and see what errors you will get.

Comment: Added it. But I think I've added enough errors so far, I'll leave the rest up to OP

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to correct the errors you mentioned. But I still don`t really understand how the pointers work. Now the compiler only gives error messages about the pointer: http://ideone.com/JZtATl

Comment: You are mixing up file handlers (`FILE*`) and strings (`char*`). You cannot assign the return value of `fopen` to a string, since it returns a pointer to the type `FILE`. I can't go into detail about everything that is wrong with your code (e.g. `copying` still returns an incorrect type), but you just check out the I/O part of the C standard library.